# Preventing pending console application by entering to edit mode

Tags: c#, console

I use next code for printing the progress in console. But since I use quick edit mode if I click inside console black area the white cursor appears and my application becomes pended. How can I prevent such behaviour continuing to use the quick edit mode?

```
public static void WriteTheSameLine(String message)
{
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
    int maxCharacterWidth = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
    if (message.Length > maxCharacterWidth)
    {
        message = message.Substring(0, maxCharacterWidth - 3) + "...";
    }
    message = message + new string(' ', maxCharacterWidth - message.Length);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

Comment: Use `Console.CursorVisible = false;` to hide the cursor.

Comment: You cannot stop the user from using the console window features, the user is always in control.  It doesn't take going into Edit mode, a simple Ctrl+S keystroke already freezes your output.  Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The very [bottom answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd) seems to explain it.

`Your CMD windows is in quick edit mode which automatically enter the edit mode when you     click on the screen. The Enter is for copy the text in the white-box and exit the edit mode.
Normally CMD only enter edit mode when you right click on the black screen and choose Mark.
To change back to normal, right click on the title bar of the windows and choose Properties, select Options tab and deselect "Quick Edit Mode" and click ok.`

Comment: But I need use exactly quick edit mode. Maybe I need change the mode temporarily during the program execution.